# google calendar api "try it" examples broken?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've been trying to get the Google PHP API working to add events to my calendar, but I keep getting POST errors, So i went to the docs on their site, but their live onpage examples of the API's keep giving me 500 errors, does anyone know why?

Like this one:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it

All you need to pass is a calenderID and auth with the google calendar scope, I did both of those and hit execute and I get a 500 internal server error from Google.

Are the Google Calender API's just broken or what?

Comment: What value are you giving for calendar ID? I am able to add events and list events in calendar using try-it examples in calendar api Documentation. Do you have access to the calendar which you are using in the request?

Comment: @SGC, hmm I suspect not..